# Did the "Command" string output from the "HTTP Receiver/ProcessStarterOutput" vanish in Tibco 6?

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I migrated a project from 5 -> 6 using the magic button.  The project has an error in the xpath expression of a logger.  Previously I was outputting the ProcessStarterOutput/Command string from my HTTP Receiver into that logger.  Now it's saying that string doesn't exist (and in fact ProcessStarterOutput is no longer part of the object model for the HTTP Receiver object).

Did this move or get removed wholesale?

Comment: Wouldn't this be something that the vendor's documentation (or support staff) could answer for you?

Comment: Regarding the documentation - so far, no.  Also, it wouldn't show up on stackoverflow for others.  It's not urgent so I figure if someone knows and wants to share, then great. As far as support staff, I could ask but it's a painful process and I'd rather no.

Comment: Are you claiming that SO isn't a place where people ask questions even if the answer is documented elsewhere?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that the proper place for the vendor to maintain their documentation is on their site. :-)